# Aptana IDE - Add New Language

Tags: aptana

I'm starting to investigate Aptana's features. I come from a Dreamweaver background.
Both have great qualities I need.  But Dreamweaver doesn't quite allow me to add a new development language into their list.

There's syntax highlighting for most of the coding languages I see: PHP, HTML, etc....
But I don't see all languages I need.  Like LUA.

Is it possible to add a new language type into Aptana, from a Preferences side?
Seems most IDE's don't allow for that kind of extensibility.  Which forces me to use multiple IDE's.

I'm not expecting a perfect IDE, but I would like to know if Aptana can go that far.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about Eclipse is that you can attach other plugins to get the support you need.

As far as I see, you can install the LuaEclipse (http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/), or some other plugin that support LUA, on top of the studio (using the "Install new software" menu under the Help).

You can also work your way by installing a classing Eclipse, then Aptana, and then LUA. Note however, that there will be no interaction between LUA and Aptana Studio. Each editor support will take over some file extensions and do its own.

Hope that helps